# Laravel 8 MongoDB sort by property in other document

Tags: laravel, mongodb, api

We are using jenssegers/mongodb in laravel 8, now the problem is the need to apply sort on the second document column but it's not working at all. Tried with a different solution.

Comment: You need to add some sample how your db look like and what have you tried and what you expect.

Comment: Using `sortBy()` ?

Comment: There are two collection
1) Users {
id,
basicInfo:{
fullName,
dob,
gender
}
}

2) Post{
id,
title,
user_id
}


We are fetching all post and auther from user collection using relation and want to apply sort on fullName field, But not working.